# How does google map API works?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i would like to know how the Google map API works. We know that Google API uses OAuth 2.0 for its security purpose. I have analyzed the OAuth architecture. Here the two concepts plays a major role.

1.Authorization

2.Authentication

So, Google map authorize the request by generated SHA1 key. i would like to know how does the authentication done here? can anyone help me to clarify this doubt.

Comment: I was hoping to use Google Map API with OAuth 2.0, but it seems like they only support API keys or client id/signatures. Did you figure anything else out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how this OAuth2 flow process for google maps api, please read it [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)

if you want a detail about OAuth it self, please read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16625_01/doc.50/e37518/oau_using_oauth.htm)

Comment: I came to know google uses OpenId as Authentication. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

you need to refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/auth#registering_authorized_urls

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth

But at the end on come security basis from google side they dose not declare the process behind the authentication algorithm.
i hope that this is helpful for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can read in visit  Click [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Comment: i am not asked about how to implement.